# Access a variable outside of a trycatch block - Python

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a try-catch block in a file, and I wanna use the value of the variable in another file.

I have this:-

```py
try:
    cnx = connect(user=database_username, password=database_password,
                  host=database_hostname,
                  database=database_name)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cnx.close()
```

But when I do

```py
from database import cursor
```

I get

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'cursor' from 'database'
```

Not I know this happens because the `cursos` is async and inside of a try-catch block

The question is how can I solve that?

Comment: You would normally import a function or a class rather than a variable.  If you import a variable, the variable must be global and defined at the time of the import.  Further, importing a variable decouples it (it just copies it into the importing namespace), so any changes made to it after it's been imported will not be reflected in the other file.  You'd probably be better off defining a function `get_cursor()`, then importing that function and calling it when you want the current value of `cursor`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, this is a good answer, why did you post it as a comment?